# matching keywords to a series of text comments

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I have two sets of information:

1. A csv file where every row has a comment, e.g:

   a. I love football
     b. Rugby is a tough game
     c. Hello World
2. Another csv file that list words related to sports, e.g:

   a. tennis
     b. football
     c. rugby

What I want to do is: 
  a. find whether any of the words in the second file appears at least once in every individual rows of the first file.
  b. If it appears at least once, it should be categorize as sports against every comment, else others.

The output file should look like:

```
Comments                          category
  a. I love football               sports
  b. Rugby is a tough game         sports
  c. Hello World                   others
```

I want to do this exercise in R. I explored str_detect & grepl function in R but not achieving the desire output.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please include [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with sample input, current output, and expected output

Comment: I would suggest to split to comment on file one into columns delimited by space and then lookup all the columns from table one with the keys in table two and set up the flags.

I do not have access to R now, else I could get you the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach that iterates over the keywords and matches the sentences using `grepl`.  Depending on how clean the sentence data is you may want to consider `agrepl` which allows for fuzzy matching (but may also result in false positives).

```
df <- data.frame(sentences=c("I love football", "Rugby is a tough game", "Hello World"))
keywords <- c("tennis", "football", "rugby")

cbind(df, sapply(keywords, function(x) grepl(x, df$sentences, ignore.case = TRUE)))

               sentences tennis football rugby
 1       I love football  FALSE     TRUE FALSE
 2 Rugby is a tough game  FALSE    FALSE  TRUE
 3           Hello World  FALSE    FALSE FALSE
```

Re-reading your post, if you just want any rather than individual sports to be flagged you can do:

```
cbind(df, sports = rowSums(sapply(keywords, function(x) grepl(x, df$sentences, ignore.case = TRUE))) > 0)
              sentences sports
1       I love football   TRUE
2 Rugby is a tough game   TRUE
3           Hello World  FALSE
```

Comment: Thnks for the answer. Remember the output file should have only two columns . The text columns and the category columns. If any word in the text contains any word from the category file, the variable category(in the output file) should have value "sports" else "others". Your solution is partially helping me out but in reality I would be dealing with 100s of keywords. Hence creating those many variables wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I just edited before you made your comment to allow for that.

Comment: In your desired approach, what happens when a sentence matches multiple keywords?